# Google Sheets: how to multiply two lists if condition applies in each row

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of colors in column A (it could be A2:A)

| A1 | Colors | Multiply |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A2 | Red | 0 |
| A3 | Blue | 1 |
| A4 | Orange | 0 |

And I have types in column B (it could be as long as B2:B)

| B1 | Types |
| --- | --- |
| B2 | Apple |
| B3 | Banana |
| B4 | Kiwi |

now how can I make this list of Colors and multiply to Types just for those rows with Multiply column is 1

|  | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Red |  | Red |
| 3 | Blue | Apple | Blue-Apple |
| 4 | Blue | Banana | Blue-Banana |
| 5 | Blue | Kiwi | Blue-Kiwi |
| 6 | Orange |  | Orange |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given 'Colours' in A, 'Multiply' in B & 'Types' in C:

```
=arrayformula(lambda(
colours,
multiply,
types,
unique(flatten(colours&if(multiply,"-"&transpose(types),))))(
filter(A2:A,A2:A<>""),
filter(B2:B,B2:B<>""),
filter(C2:C,C2:C<>"")))
```

Comment: Thank you, with this formula, an extra row appears: "Blue-"

=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(A2:A&IF(B2:B,"-"&transpose(C2:C),))))

"Red", "Blue-Apple", "Blue-Banana", "Blue-Kiwi", "Blue-", "Orange"

Comment: Got it, removed extra space in column, formula is correct